# Algebraic division with two variables? $\frac{a^3 + b^3}{a+b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rational-functions

I know there's a formula for this, but I would like to know how to do algebraic division the long way - would appreciate if you can guide me along.

> How can I use long division for
>   $$\frac{a^3 + b^3}{a+b}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{a^3+b^3}{a+b} &= \frac{a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3-3a^2b-3ab^2}{a+b}\\
&= \frac{(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)}{a+b}\\
&= \frac{(a+b)^3}{a+b}-\frac{3ab(a+b)}{a+b}\\
&=(a+b)^2-3ab\\
&=a^2+2ab+b^2-3ab\\
&=a^2-ab+b^2
\end{align}

Comment: Clearest answer by far - thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

We want to find $P$, a polynomial of $a$ and $b$,  so that $$ (a^3+b^3)\div (a+b)=P $$

or, rearranging,

$$a^3 + b ^3 = (a+b)\cdot P.$$

We don't know what $P $ is exactly, but it should begin with $a^2$, 
because that way we'll get the $a^3$ term we need on the right.
So suppose $P = a^2 + Q$.  Then we have:

$$\begin{align}
a^3+b^3&= (a+b)P \\
& =(a+b)(a^2 + Q) \\
& = a^3 + a^2b + (a+b)Q\\
\end{align}
$$

Now the $a^2b$ on the right is no good (because there isn't one on the left), but if $Q= -ab + R$ then we can get rid of it:

$$\begin{align}
a^3+b^3&= a^3 + a^2b + (a+b)Q \\
& = a^3 + a^2b + (a+b)(-ab + R) \\
& = a^3 + a^2b + -a^2b - ab^2 + (a+b)R \\
& = a^3 - ab^2 + (a+b)R \\
\end{align}
$$

We got rid of the $a^2b$, but now we have  $-ab^2$ on the right that we need to get rid of.  If we have $R = b^2 + S$ we can get rid of that too:

$$\begin{align}
a^3+b^3& = a^3 - ab^2 + (a+b)R \\
& = a^3 - ab^2 + (a+b)(b^2 + S) \\ 
& = a^3 - ab^2 + ab^2 +b^3 + (a+b)S \\
& = a^3 + b^3 + (a+b)S
\end{align}$$

Now if $S = 0$ we win.

So $P = a^2 + Q = a^2 -ab + R = a^2 - ab + b^2 + S = a^2 -ab + b^2$, and that's the answer you wanted.

That's how long division always goes. (Long division of numbers works the same way. For example, to divide 357 by 17, you ask what $P$ will make  $357 = (10+ 7)P$, then observe you want $P=20 +Q$, and so on.)  For practice, you might try dividing $a^2+2ab+b^2$ by $a+b$ using this method, since you already know what the answer is.

Comment: I like this! Especially since the basic idea behind it can be applied to other problems too (i.e. not necessarily about division).

Comment: Very detailed and easy to follow - I didn't really apply this intuition to long division - thanks for this clever response!

Answer (score 4):

If you can do division with one variable, then just treat this example like that, making $a$ play the role of the variable, and $b$ of a constant. It would go something like this:

$$a+b\overline{\Big)a^3+0a^2+0a+b^3}$$

$a$ goes into $a^3$ $a^2$ times, and so on, as polynomial long division works.

Comment: Have tried this - a bit long winded as with polynomial division - but got the answer - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

$\begin{array}\\
a^n-b^n
&=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\\
&=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{n-1-k}b^k\\
\end{array}
$

and,
if $n$ is odd,
and $n = 2m+1$,

$\begin{array}\\
a^n+b^n
&=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+...-ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\\
&=(a+b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^ka^{n-1-k}b^k\\
&=(a+b)\sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^ka^{2m-k}b^k\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks for showing the generalized form of factoring this expression - very insightful :)